# Kinect causing framerate limitation in Unity3D

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, kinect, frame-rate

I'm currently developing a Unity3D project which uses both Oculus Rift and Kinect. However, Kinect is limiting the framerate to 30 fps and the Rift needs 60 fps to achieve a fluent experience. I'm using the official It's definitely not a performance issue.

I'm using [this](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Microsoft_SDK) wrapper with the official Kinect SDK.

I've narrowed the cause down to this piece of code bellow. I'm suspecting that the getSkeleton() function is blocking the main thread until it has recieved data from the Kinect. Since the Kinect only runs at 30 fps the rest of the application cannot run faster than that.

```
    public bool pollSkeleton () {
    if (!updatedSkeleton)
    {
        updatedSkeleton = true; 
        if (kinect.pollSkeleton())
        {
            newSkeleton = true;
            System.Int64 cur = kinect.getSkeleton().liTimeStamp;
            System.Int64 diff = cur - ticks;
            ticks = cur;
            deltaTime = diff / (float)1000;
            processSkeleton();
        }
    }
    return newSkeleton;
}
```

Perhaps I could run a seperate thread, but since I have no experience with multithreaded programming I was wondering if anyone had a more simple solution?

My guess is that a lot of Oculus Rift developers will be using the Kinect+Unity3D combo and thus run into the same limitation as me. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
I created a seperate thread for polling the skeleton Info from the kinect: Here's the complete code for the modified SkeletonWrapper.cs. Hope it will help some of you guys struggling with the same issue.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Kinect;
using System.Threading;

public class SkeletonWrapper : MonoBehaviour {

public DeviceOrEmulator devOrEmu;
private Kinect.KinectInterface kinect;

private bool updatedSkeleton = false;
private bool newSkeleton = false;

[HideInInspector]
public Kinect.NuiSkeletonTrackingState[] players;
[HideInInspector]
public int[] trackedPlayers;
[HideInInspector]
public Vector3[,] bonePos;
[HideInInspector]
public Vector3[,] rawBonePos;
[HideInInspector]
public Vector3[,] boneVel;
[HideInInspector]
public Quaternion[,] boneLocalOrientation;
[HideInInspector]
public Quaternion[,] boneAbsoluteOrientation;

public Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionTrackingState[,] boneState;    
private System.Int64 ticks;
private float deltaTime;

private Matrix4x4 kinectToWorld;
public Matrix4x4 flipMatrix;

private Thread thread = null;
private bool isThreadRunning = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    kinect = devOrEmu.getKinect();
    players = new Kinect.NuiSkeletonTrackingState[Kinect.Constants.NuiSkeletonCount];
    trackedPlayers = new int[Kinect.Constants.NuiSkeletonMaxTracked];
    trackedPlayers[0] = -1;
    trackedPlayers[1] = -1;
    bonePos = new Vector3[2,(int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count];
    rawBonePos = new Vector3[2,(int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count];
    boneVel = new Vector3[2,(int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count];

    boneState = new Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionTrackingState[2,(int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count];
    boneLocalOrientation = new Quaternion[2, (int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count];
    boneAbsoluteOrientation = new Quaternion[2, (int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count];

    //create the transform matrix that converts from kinect-space to world-space
    Matrix4x4 trans = new Matrix4x4();
    trans.SetTRS( new Vector3(-kinect.getKinectCenter().x,
                              kinect.getSensorHeight()-kinect.getKinectCenter().y,
                              -kinect.getKinectCenter().z),
                 Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one );
    Matrix4x4 rot = new Matrix4x4();
    Quaternion quat = new Quaternion();
    double theta = Mathf.Atan((kinect.getLookAt().y+kinect.getKinectCenter().y-kinect.getSensorHeight()) / (kinect.getLookAt().z + kinect.getKinectCenter().z));
    float kinectAngle = (float)(theta * (180 / Mathf.PI));
    quat.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-kinectAngle, 0, 0);
    rot.SetTRS( Vector3.zero, quat, Vector3.one);

    //final transform matrix offsets the rotation of the kinect, then translates to a new center
    kinectToWorld = flipMatrix*trans*rot;

    thread = new Thread(ThreadUpdate);
    thread.Start(); 
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    if (isThreadRunning)
    {
        isThreadRunning = false;
        thread.Abort();
        thread = null;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void LateUpdate () {
    updatedSkeleton = false;
    newSkeleton = false;
}

private void ThreadUpdate()
{
    isThreadRunning = true;

    while (isThreadRunning)
    {
        // This function is capping the FPS to 30. 
        if (kinect.pollSkeleton())
        {
            System.Int64 cur = kinect.getSkeleton().liTimeStamp;
            System.Int64 diff = cur - ticks;
            ticks = cur;
            deltaTime = diff / (float)1000;
            processSkeleton();
            newSkeleton = true;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// First call per frame checks if there is a new skeleton frame and updates,
/// returns true if there is new data
/// Subsequent calls do nothing have the same return as the first call.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// A <see cref="System.Boolean"/>
/// </returns>
public bool pollSkeleton () {
    //if (!updatedSkeleton)
    //{
    //    updatedSkeleton = true;
    //    //this function is capping the FPS to 30. 
    //    //It might be blocking the main thread because it waits for the kinects skeleton input which only runs 30 fps
    //    //possible solution: run function in seperate thread
    //    if (kinect.pollSkeleton())
    //    {
    //        newSkeleton = true;
    //        System.Int64 cur = kinect.getSkeleton().liTimeStamp;
    //        System.Int64 diff = cur - ticks;
    //        ticks = cur;
    //        deltaTime = diff / (float)1000;
    //        processSkeleton();
    //    }
    //}
    return newSkeleton;
}

private void processSkeleton () {
    int[] tracked = new int[Kinect.Constants.NuiSkeletonMaxTracked];
    tracked[0] = -1;
    tracked[1] = -1;
    int trackedCount = 0;
    //update players
    for (int ii = 0; ii < Kinect.Constants.NuiSkeletonCount; ii++)
    {
        players[ii] = kinect.getSkeleton().SkeletonData[ii].eTrackingState;
        if (players[ii] == Kinect.NuiSkeletonTrackingState.SkeletonTracked)
        {
            tracked[trackedCount] = ii;
            trackedCount++;
        }
    }
    //this should really use trackingID instead of index, but for now this is fine
    switch (trackedCount)
    {
    case 0:
        trackedPlayers[0] = -1;
        trackedPlayers[1] = -1;
        break;
    case 1:
        //last frame there were no players: assign new player to p1
        if (trackedPlayers[0] < 0 && trackedPlayers[1] < 0)
            trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
        //last frame there was one player, keep that player in the same spot
        else if (trackedPlayers[0] < 0) 
            trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[0];
        else if (trackedPlayers[1] < 0)
            trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
        //there were two players, keep the one with the same index (if possible)
        else
        {
            if (tracked[0] == trackedPlayers[0])
                trackedPlayers[1] = -1;
            else if (tracked[0] == trackedPlayers[1])
                trackedPlayers[0] = -1;
            else
            {
                trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
                trackedPlayers[1] = -1;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        //last frame there were no players: assign new players to p1 and p2
        if (trackedPlayers[0] < 0 && trackedPlayers[1] < 0)
        {
            trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
            trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[1];
        }
        //last frame there was one player, keep that player in the same spot
        else if (trackedPlayers[0] < 0)
        {
            if (trackedPlayers[1] == tracked[0])
                trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[1];
            else{
                trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
                trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[1];
            }
        }
        else if (trackedPlayers[1] < 0)
        {
            if (trackedPlayers[0] == tracked[1])
                trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[0];
            else{
                trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
                trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[1];
            }
        }
        //there were two players, keep the one with the same index (if possible)
        else
        {
            if (trackedPlayers[0] == tracked[1] || trackedPlayers[1] == tracked[0])
            {
                trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[1];
                trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[0];
            }
            else
            {
                trackedPlayers[0] = tracked[0];
                trackedPlayers[1] = tracked[1];
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    //update the bone positions, velocities, and tracking states)
    for (int player = 0; player < 2; player++)
    {
        //print(player + ", " +trackedPlayers[player]);
        if (trackedPlayers[player] >= 0)
        {
            for (int bone = 0; bone < (int)Kinect.NuiSkeletonPositionIndex.Count; bone++)
            {
                Vector3 oldpos = bonePos[player,bone];

                bonePos[player,bone] = kinectToWorld.MultiplyPoint3x4(kinect.getSkeleton().SkeletonData[trackedPlayers[player]].SkeletonPositions[bone]);
                //bonePos[player,bone] = kinectToWorld.MultiplyPoint3x4(bonePos[player, bone]);
                rawBonePos[player, bone] = kinect.getSkeleton().SkeletonData[trackedPlayers[player]].SkeletonPositions[bone];


                Kinect.NuiSkeletonBoneOrientation[] or = kinect.getBoneOrientations(kinect.getSkeleton().SkeletonData[trackedPlayers[player]]);
                boneLocalOrientation[player,bone] = or[bone].hierarchicalRotation.rotationQuaternion.GetQuaternion();
                boneAbsoluteOrientation[player,bone] = or[bone].absoluteRotation.rotationQuaternion.GetQuaternion();

                //print("index " + bone + ", start" + (int)or[bone].startJoint + ", end" + (int)or[bone].endJoint);

                boneVel[player,bone] = (bonePos[player,bone] - oldpos) / deltaTime;
                boneState[player,bone] = kinect.getSkeleton().SkeletonData[trackedPlayers[player]].eSkeletonPositionTrackingState[bone];
                //print(kinect.getSkeleton().SkeletonData[player].Position.z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about how the Kinect SDK works.  It's possible that it's already managing a background thread that is doing the skeletal tracking, and the pollSkeleton method simply blocks until the next frame is available.

This seems like a reasonable assumption, since the SDK supports both polling and event based notifications, implying that if you don't poll, something else will trigger the fetch of the next frame and send you the event.

If this is the case, then you can solve your problem by simply scanning the timestamp on the skeleton data that's available from the thread...

```
System.Int64 lastSkeletonTime = 0;
public bool pollSkeleton () 
{
  if (kinect.getSkeleton().liTimeStamp > lastSkeletonTime) {
    updatedSkeleton = true; 
    newSkeleton = true;
    System.Int64 cur = kinect.getSkeleton().liTimeStamp;
    System.Int64 diff = cur - lastSkeletonTime;
    deltaTime = diff / (float)1000;
    lastSkeletonTime = cur;
    processSkeleton();
  }
  return newSkeleton;
}
```

If this doesn't work, then most likely you will need to launch a background thread, or switch to handling the events.